# Form based on a one-to-many relationship - just show parent records with child actions

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, one with parent records, and one with child records.

The child records are displayed in a subform attached to the bottom of the form containing the parent records.

I want the main form's recordset to only consist of those parent records for which child records exist. However, when I try to do this, I get multiple parent records (i.e. if I flick through the records, I have to pass four parent records if there are four associated child records, etc.).

I think I need to use a GROUP BY but when I try to create a query to do this (so I might be able to base my form on it) it tells me that I need to GROUP on all the fields in the query, then it errors when I do so.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are populating the main (parent) form, but if you find the `Record Source` for this form, from its Property Sheet, then click the build button (...) to invoke the **Query Builder**, you can just add in (Show) the child table. Assuming there already exists a relationship between the two tables, this will create an INNER JOIN. If there isn't already a relationship (a join) then drag and drop from the primary key in the parent table to the foreign key in the child table.

You don't need to include any fields from the child table, but you will have to include all the fields you need from the parent table in the query grid. Adding the child table creates, as I mentioned, an INNER JOIN, which will only show records from the parent table if they have records in the child table.

Close and Save the Query Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andy. However the problem with the above is that I get multiple rows for each parent record - if a parent record has two child records, I get two rows. What this means for my form is that I have to scroll through 'duplicates' of the same parent record depending on how many child records it has...

Comment: This hasn't solved my problem I'm afraid. Any other suggestions?